# Is this correct please?

Tags: verb, sentence-structure, word-order, adverb, curiosity

"Ich spiele gern Rugby jeden Tag".    Please let me know if this sentence is correct.  I know that "Jeden Tag" can be placed at the beginning -- but can we put "gern" and "jeden Tag" after the verb?
Vielen Dank im Voraus!

Answer (score 2):

I mean the "jeden Tag" sounds like it's tagged on to the sentence. Like "Ich spiele gerne Rugby" is already a full functioning sentence, so yes you can use the gerne after the verb. But as said the "jeden Tag" at the end sounds not horribly wrong, but somewhat dissonant.

Maybe try something like,

```
"Ich spiele gerne Rugby, wenn (es mir) möglich (ist) jeden Tag.".
"Ich spiele gerne täglich eine Runde Rugby." 
"Ich spiele täglich Rubgy und mache das sehr gerne"
```

Comment: I agree putting "jeden Tag" at the end sounds odd, but what's wrong with "Ich spiele jeden Tag gerne Rugby." and "Ich spiele gerne jeden Tag Rugby.", both of which sound natural to me? (The second one slightly shifts the meaning, though, in that the "gerne" now expresses a preference for playing rugby being a daily activity, rather than a preference for playing rugby itself.)

Comment: The first sentence still sounds a little odd to me, but if I'd replace "jeden Tag" with other temporal specifiers like "immer wieder", "Sonntags", "in den Ferien" and so on then it sounds ok. The combination of "jeden Tag" and "gerne" seems to always make it sound as if you like it as a daily activity and not just for  the activity itself. Though I agree "Ich spiele gerne jeden Tag Rugby" also sounds quite nice.

Comment: "as if you like it as a daily activity and not just for the activity itself" - interesting, precisely that is my impression from the *second* sentence ("gerne jeden Tag"), whereas the first one ("jeden Tag gerne") sounds entirely neutral to me, as if just praising the activity itself.

Comment: Yeah I can see what you mean, "jeden Tag gerne" can be read as "Jeden Tags auf neue freue ich mich Rugby zu speilen", but something aobut the combination "Ich spiele jeden tag gerne Rugby" still feels odd, like as if one of these words is too much and cannot exist as it's own clause either. But I can't pin down exactly what it is.